# Data transpose function in R not working properly

Tags: r, import, transpose, data-manipulation

I am using R to do some work but I'm having difficulties in transposing data.

My data is in rows and the columns are different variables. When using the function phyDat, the author indicates a transpose function because importing data is stored in columns.

So I use the following code to finish this process:

```
#read file from local disk in csv format. this format can be generated by save as function of excel.
origin <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
origin <- t(origin)
events <- phyDat(origin, type="USER", levels=c(0,1))
```

When I check the data shown in R studio, it is transposed but the result it is not. So I went back and modified the code as follows:

```
origin <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
events <- phyDat(origin, type="USER", levels=c(0,1))
```

This time the data does not reflect transposed data, and the result is consistent with it.

How I currently solve the problem is transposing the data in CSV file before importing to R. Is there something I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: There's a neat and efficient reshape function in R that I think you can use: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.0/topics/reshape

Comment: It's not clear that you need to transpose the data based on the information you've provided. Please indicate the structure of your data. N (rows) x M (columns)? Rows are species? Columns are genetic bases?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by doing an extra step as follows:

```
#read file from local disk in csv format. this format can be generated by save as function of excel.
origin <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
origin <- as.data.frame(t(origin))
events <- phyDat(origin, type="USER", levels=c(0,1))
```

Maybe it is too late but hope it could help other users with the same problem.